# How to use remove duplicates in r but also keep some conditional duplicates

Tags: r

I have a dataset of genes grouped by region, and I measure their distances between each other in their regions.

Currently to calculate total distance across all regions I use `unique()` on my region distances however, this doesn't acount for the chance 2 regions may have the exact same number, and should both be kept when I sum the total distance.

I think I am not sure how to incorperate this condition into my code, the other questions I find here do not have conditions based on other columns of data like I need.

For example my data looks like this:

```
Gene  region  region.distance
ACE      1       10
AGT      1       10
BRCA     2       20
DVL1     3       10
NOTCH3   4       40
```

I then use this code to gain the unique values in `region.distance` to sum the total distance:

```
total.distance <- sum(unique(df$region.distance))
```

However this does not account for regions 1 and 3 both having a distance of 10. My output total distance for my example data above should be 80 not 70.

Is it possible for me to incorporate within `unqiue()` an if statement, for example using `diff(df$region)` but also including that if it's still a duplicate but in a different region that should be kept in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the duplicates within the group and then `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(region.distance)) %>%
  pull(region.distance) %>% sum
#[1] 80
```

Similarly, in base R we can do

```
sum(subset(df, !ave(region.distance, region, FUN = duplicated))$region.distance)
#[1] 80
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = structure(1:5, .Label = c("ACE", "AGT", 
"BRCA", "DVL1", "NOTCH3"), class = "factor"), region = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), region.distance = c(10L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 40L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df),by = c("region", "region.distance"))[, sum(region.distance)]
#[1] 80
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = structure(1:5, .Label = c("ACE", "AGT", 
"BRCA", "DVL1", "NOTCH3"), class = "factor"), region = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), region.distance = c(10L, 10L, 20L, 10L, 40L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```